# Find the number from 10 statements

Tags: mathematics, liars, number-theory

You are given the following ten statements and are asked to determine a particular ***number***.

> 1. At least one of statements 7 and 8 is true.
> 2. This either is the first true or the first false statement.
> 3. The ***number*** is a prime number.
> 4. The first true statement multiplied by the last false statement divides the ***number***.
> 5. The number of divisors of the ***number*** is greater than the sum of the numbers of the true statements.
> 6. The ***number*** has exactly 4 distinct prime divisors.
> 7. The ***number*** is bigger than 1000.
> 8. The numbers of true statements do not equal the numbers of false statement.
> 9. One of the divisors is a cube number bigger than 1.
> 10. There are 3 consecutive False statements and 3 consecutive True statements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Our number is

> 840

And the truth/falsehood of the statements is

> 1. At least one of statements 7 and 8 is true.  **False.**
>  2. This either is the first true or the first false statement. **True.**
>  3. The number is a prime number.    **False.**
>  4. The first true statement multiplied by the last false statement divides the number.  **True.**
>  5. The number of divisors of the number is greater than the sum of the numbers of the true statements. **True.**
>  6. The number has exactly 4 prime divisors.  **True.**
>  7. The number is bigger than 1000. **False.**
>  8. The numbers of true statements do not equal the numbers of false statement **False.**
>  9. One of the divisors is a cube number bigger than 1. **True.**
>  10. There are 3 consecutive False statements and 3 consecutive True statements. **False.**

---

Assume statement 1 is true. Then

> statement 2 can either be true, in which case it would be false because it isn't the first true statement; or it could be false, in which case it would be true because it would be the first false statement. Therefore 1 must be false.

This implies that

> 7 and 8 are both false. We now know the number is smaller or equal to 1000, and the number of false statements equals the number of true statements (so we must have 5 each).

Now assume 3 is true. Then, we get that

> as the number is prime, 4, 6 and 9 are all false, which with 1, 7 and 8, leaves us with 6 false statements, which is impossible. So 3 is false and the number is not prime.

Continuing on,

> of the remaining statements, exactly one is false, the rest are all true. If either of 4, 5 or 6 is false, this makes 10 also false. So 4, 5 and 6 are true.

Assume 9 is false. Then for 5 to be true,

> the number has to have more than 2+4+5+6+10=27 divisors. But as the number is smaller than 1000, this is impossible unless it has a cube divisor greater than 1, which would mean 9 is true. So 9 has to be true.

6, 7 and 9 imply

> our number is $2^3 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 = 840$. It has 32 divisors, so for 5 to be true, 10 can't be true or the sum of the true statements would be too high. This leaves 2 as the last true statement.